# Internet Connection Turns off while changing mac address on Kali Linux 2020.2

Tags: networking, kali-linux, mac-address

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
ifconfig eth0 up
service network-manager restart
ping www.google.com
```

[image: Complete Output Here]

While changing my mac address on Kali Linux 2020.2 with this ifconfig method,I lost my internet connection. Another tool called `macchanger` works perfectly but this does not work. This happens with Kali Linux 2019.1  and Kali Linux 2016.2 also.

Comment: Please don't post Console output as images. This could easily be preseted as text

Comment: Pinging an IP address on the Internet works? Like `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: No..It does not work..

Comment: Stop using Kali. Its not designed for people with your level of skill.

Answer (score 1):

When you change your MAC address, you have to make sure, that your communication partners learn about this as fast as possible. If not, your connectionwill drop, until the ARP-process restarts after ARP cache timeout.

So you need to purge local ARP cache and send an unsolicitated ARP `is-at` to anyone who will listen. I assume, that this is waht "macchanger" and friends do.